# System.Text.Json custom descriminator that isn't the first field?

Tags: c#, system.json

I have some JSON retrieved from a database that I cannot alter. I want to polymorphically deserialise based on a field in the object. I understand I can supply a custom name via the attribute `[JsonPolymorphic(TypeDiscriminatorPropertyName = "$discriminator")]` but this complains as the field I want to use is not the first of the object. Is my only option here a full custom converter or is there a simpler way to just specify the field I want when it's not the first?

Comment: Can you add the exact error message?